# Having same Unit/UI tests for both project Targets?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I want to add unit and UI testing to my iOS project on which it has 2 Targets A and B. A and B are flavors of the app with the same logic but with a different style (colors, fonts..).

When I try to add a Test target from the + button it asks me to choose a Target to be tested either A or B. my tests are the same on both targets.

This is where I am confused. How can I have same units tests across all targets? Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple targets, then there are some steps that will help us configure the single XCTestCase file for both targets that are mentioned below:

**Step 1:** Right click the existing target SampleTests and then click duplicate. Then rename the test target to differentiate and rename the Info.plist for all and give corresponding Info.plist file path in Corresponding Target-> Build Settings-> Info.plist file name.

**Step 2:** Choose corresponding host application for both test targets.

**Step 3:** Add a flag in active compilation flags for both test target to differentiate current target while in runtime. Select Test target -> Build Settings -> Active compilation condition

**Step 4:** While adding or creating new test case file, make sure you added for the both test targets. Check Target Membership for the existing files too.

**Step 5:** Importing project module depending upon current Target.

#if A

@testable import A

#else

@testable import B

#endif

Step 6: Click Target and Edit Scheme and Add Test target.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't have two `host applications` in single test target. You have to select (n)one.**

But if the code is the same for both targets, it doesn't really matter which one you choose, I guess?

Of course you could do the same as you probably did for your logic code, that means to make the same (test) code "member" of two test targets. However I don't see the point in testing the same stuff twice.

It also seems to be possible to set up your tests, so that they don't depend on a specific `host application`, like described in the following link, but this also comes with some restrictions.
https://clean-swift.com/how-to-make-your-unit-tests-run-faster

I would go with the first approach: Just choose one host (app target), and go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maintaining two targets for basically same code I will advise you two maintain a single target and customize each flavours with schemes and configs. This also allows you to share those schemes and configs in your single test target allowing you to test different flavours of the same app.